# unexpected result when using a list comprehension on a list of booleans Python

Tags: python, boolean, list-comprehension

```
r=[True, False,True,False, False]
print([i for i in r if str(r[i])=="True"])
```

this code gives the following unexpected result:
[False, False, False]

Why is this the behavior? I would expect:
[True, True]

Comment: Python for loops are for-each loops (i.e. iterator-based for-loops). `i` will not hold the index of the elements in `r`, it will hold the *elements* of r.

Answer (score 11):

`i` is a boolean with a value of `True` or `False`. If you use it as an index in `r[i]`, you will get either `r[0]` or `r[1]` because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

You can picture it as `r[int(i)]` and `int(True) == 1`, `int(False) == 0`.

What you probably mean is:

```
print([i for i in range(len(r)) if str(r[i])=="True"])
```

where `i` is an integer or:

```
print([i for i in r if str(i)=="True"])
```

where `i` is a boolean.

Note that if `i` is a boolean, there is little point in `if str(i) == "True"`. A more concise way of writing it would be:

```
print([i for i in r if i])
```

or even using the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function:

```
it = filter(None, r)
print(list(it))
```

Comment: I think `[i for i in r if str(i) == "True"]` is a little cleaner.

Comment: @huck_cussler Thanks I added this too.

Comment: *"the interpreter is going to translate r[i] to r[int(i)"* - nope. See the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: @LukasGraf I had a feeling of uncertainty whilst writing this. Thanks for pointing this out. Shame I already upvoted your answer!

Comment: @SheelaSingla if you are excluding false(-y) values from a list try [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter)

Answer (score 2):

You meant `str(i)`.

With your original code,

- on the first iteration, `i` is `True`, and as `True` has the integer value `1`, `r[i]` will be `r[1]`, which is False. The `if` condition fails.
- on the second iteration, `i` is `False`, and as `False` has the integer value `0`, `r[i]` will be `r[0]`, which is True. The `if` condition succeeds and i (which is `False`) gets added to the result.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `i` in two different ways:

- To **index** a list (`r[i]`)
- And as the iteration variable in a list comprehension `[i for i in items]`

`r[i]` would usually fail if `i` wasn't an integer - lists can only be indexed via integers. However, booleans are a special case in Python, `bool` is actually a subclass of `int`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```

That's why this even "works", and gives you surprising results.

Since there's no need to use list indexing in a list comprehension, this is what you probably meant to write:

```
>>> print([i for i in r if str(i) == "True"])
[True, True]
```

---

Also note that there is no implicit **casting** going on here, unlike what other answers previously suggested:

Python doesn't do that. It does *not* "translate r[i] to r[int(i)]".

Lets look at the string `"1"`. It will happily cast that to an `int` if you ask it to:

```
>>> int("1")
1
```

But nevertheless, using `"1"` for list indexing will never work:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst["1"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Your example only "works" because `bool` actually *is* a subclass of `int`, and `True` therefore really *is* an integer, as far as Python is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the output you want

```
r=[True, False,True,False, False]
print([i for i in r if str(i)=="True"])
```

i refers to the individual elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Jacques Gaudin is correct, that you're indexing with a boolean. An even simpler version of the code, however, would be:

```
print([i for i in r if str(i)=="True"])
```

or, of course:

```
print([i for i in r if i])
```